# use counter outside iterations, ignoring empty lines in list

Tags: python, list, iteration, counter

I'm looking for a way to use the counter outside of a loop. As in this example, the idea is to print the amount of lines from a list, ignoring empty lines. So far I think I'm using the counter in a wrong way, because it doesn't count the empty lines yet.

```
import csv
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader2 = csv.reader(f)
    reader2.next()
    linecount = len(zip(*reader2)[0])
    f.seek(0)
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    reader.next()
    counter = []
    print(linecount)
    print(type(str(counter)))
    for row in reader:
    if not row[0]: #avoid empty lines
        counter += 1
            continue
    print row
    print (int(linecount)-len(counter))
```

Comment: What is `counter` meant to be ?  a list or an integer?  Can you check your indentation too, please?

Comment: counter should be an integer. The error msg that I get is `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: If `counter` is supposed to be an integer why are you doing `counter = []` and `len(counter)`? And since `linecount` _is_ an integer , there's no point doing `int(linecount)`.

Comment: just start with `counter = 0` and don't use `len()` on it at the end

Comment: So simple as that? lol... I should have get it before

Comment: did you try my answer

Comment: many thanks, but I need csv to continue with the output in other operations.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to count the lines why are you bothering with CSV? All you need is something as simple as:

```
with open('/tmp/uni.py','r') as f:
    empty = 0
    nonempty = 1
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            nonempty +=1
        else :
            empty +=1

print empty, nonempty
```

This can be done in even fewer lines of code but I did it like this for clarity.